# Is there any way to use own Drawable class in drawable XML?

Tags: android, xml-drawable

The first problem was the Notification(..) constructor gets only resource id, not drawable. I need to display some small (dynamic) graphics in notification.
Shortly before, I was able to implement custom View, just extended View class, and implemented onDraw() method. The view works perfectly (and i used it by full class name in xml layout file). I decided (by analogy), that i can build own Drawable class and declare it in xml file, but this not works. This is my drawable:

```
public class TestDrawable extends Drawable {

  public TestDrawable() {
    this.setBounds(0, 0, this.getIntrinsicWidth(), this.getIntrinsicHeight());
  }

  @Override
  public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
      return 36;
  }

  @Override
  public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
      return 36;

  }  

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(8, 8, 3, paint);
  }

  @Override
  public void setAlpha(int alpha) {        
  }

  @Override
  public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
  }

  @Override
  public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
  }
}
```

I have checked a lot of variants of xml drawable files, constructors and combination of methods. But, draw() method even not called :(. I tested this drawable as an application icon. Other drawables, as shapes or images works as usual.

Comment: I'm not familiar with extending Drawables, but you probably should call the super() constructor within your constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but Drawable is abstract class and does not have constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The view works perfectly (and i used it by full class name in xml layout file).

For your own activity, perhaps. You cannot use custom `View` classes in any `RemoteViews` circumstance.

> I decided (by analogy), that i can build own Drawable class and declare it in xml file, but this not works.

Whether you can or cannot does not matter. An OS process displays the `Notification`. The OS process does not have your custom `Drawable` class. Hence, the OS process cannot use anything that depends upon your custom `Drawable` class.

AFAIK, you cannot create new drawable resource types in general.

Comment: Maybe. But, i know several applications, that displays text on place of icon in notification. How did they do that?
I found two ways:
1) Custom drawable
2) dynamically create bitamp with text, but this not works, because there is no way to assign drawable with notification, only by resource id!

Comment: @hydra: "i know several applications, that displays text on place of icon in notification" -- please post screenshots.

Comment: For example
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.macropinch.pearl#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLm1hY3JvcGluY2gucGVhcmwiXQ
(in the middle)
Do you think that this is 100 static drawbles?

Comment: @hydra: "Do you think that this is 100 static drawbles?" -- probably it is.